# How to verify what's noise what's real data?

Tags: machine-learning, noise

I am wondering how can I claim that I correctly catch the "noise" in my data ?

To be more specific, take Principle Component Analysis as example, we know that in PCA, after doing SVD, we can zeros out the small singular values and   reconstruct the original matrix using low-rank approximation.

Then can I claim what's been ignored is indeed noise in the data ?
Is there any evaluation metric for this ?

The only method I can come up with is simply subtract the original data from the reconstructed data.

Then, try to fit a Gaussian over it, seeing if the fitness is good.

Is that conventional method in field like DSP ??

BTW, I think in typical machine learning tasks, the measurement would be the follow up classification performance, but since I am doing purely generative model, there are no labels attached.

Answer (score 4):

The way I see it, the definition of noise would depend on the domain of the problem. Therefore the strategy for reducing it would be different on each domain.

For instance, having a noisy signal in problems like seismic formation classification or a noisy image on a face classification problem would be drastically different to the noise produced by improperly tagged data in a medical diagnostic problem or the noise because similar words with different meaning in a language classification problem for documents.

When the noise is because of a given (or a set of) data point, then the solution is as simple as ignore those data points (although identify those data points most of the time is the challenging part)

From your example I guess you are more concerning about the case when the noise is embedded into the features (like in the seismic example). Sometimes people tend to pre-process the data with a noise reduction filter like the median filter (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter). In contrast, some other people tend to reduce the dimension of the data to reduce noise, and PCA is used in this scenario.

Both strategies are valid, and normally people try both and cross-validate them to see which one gave better results.

What you did is a good metric to check gaussian noise. However, for non-gaussian noise your metric can give you false negatives (bad fitness but still good noise reduction)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question is really only related to your last paragraph, that I wanna "catch" the noise.

I think it's hard to define as Ben said.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, if you want to prove the efficacy of the noise reduction, I'd use a task-based evaluation. I assume you're doing this for some purpose, to solve some problem? If so, solve the task with the original noisy matrix and the new clean one. If the latter works better, what was discarded was noise, *for the purposes of the task you're interested in*. I think some objective measure of noise is pretty hard to define.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this. it is very resoureful, needs good time to understand.
https://sci2s.ugr.es/noisydata#Introduction%20to%20Noise%20in%20Data%20Mining